# Android Calendar API vs Calendar Provider API

Tags: java, android, api, calendar

I'm a little bit confused about the difference between the two. An example of the Calendar API is supposedly located here: http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-android-sample/instructions.html, but the author himself suggests using the Calendar Provider API, details about which are here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html.

Can someone explain to me the difference between the two, and which would be better for me to use for a simple calendar app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have not gone through much of the google api code, but i think if you use google api, you will have to handle network syncing of the calendar, but Since syncing is already done by android calendar provider, You can use calendar provider by using query, insert, delete statements instead of learning the google api specification.

Further i guess using google api code, you will have to handle oauth authentication. Which is not required in case of calendar provider

So Provider should be easier.

Answer (score 0):

CalendarProvider is built-in, so you don't have to handle networking, authentication etc. But it is a kind of a contentprovider, so you'll have to use sqlite-queries and cursor mapping to collect data. Try [this library](http://howrobotswork.wordpress.com/2014/01/02/calendarwrapper-a-simple-and-uncomplete-library-above-the-calendarprovider/), it does all the mapping for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to mention: Calendar Provider does not support event attachments so if you need to use attachments, you will have to handle them via Google Calendar API.